# What happens if the AC evaporator ices over?

Tags: ford, hvac, fusion

I am thinking of replacing the air conditioning evaporator temperature sensor in my 2011 ford fusion with a resistor, since the dash must be removed to replace the sensor. The warning that goes with this procedure is that if you use the air conditioner in very cold weather the AC evaporator may ice up. What harm could come from the evaporator freezing ? maybe water will build up behind the dash leading to a musty smell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the evaporator becomes iced , much less or no air will blow through it an the AC will not cool the car. It probably will not "harm" anything , the AC will just work poorly , likely including the defrosters.

Comment: I see. so no permanent damage is done, I would just have to wait for the evaporator to defrost, and the resulting water could drain out via the evaporator drain.

Comment: Also, do all cars have a way of sensing if the compressor is icing ? Is icing only a problem on a properly filled AC system when running the AC to defrost the windows in cold weather ?